# How can put Numeral.js library in pug file Node js?

Tags: node.js, pug, nodemailer

I am using nodoe js and nodemailer. How can I use numeral.js to format numbers in pug file. Something like this.

```
#{numeral(number).format('0,0.00')}
```

If try this i getting numeral is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `numeral` function to your template otherwise (as you already stated) it will not be defined. Since you did not specify any code it is hard to tell how exactly you start the rendering of you pug file.

I usually handle it that way that I define a helper function which I then pass to the template:

```
const numeral = require('numeral');
function formatNumber(num) {
   return numeral(number).format('0,0.00');
}
```

Usage in the template works like this:
`#{formatNumber(number)}`